# Deserialize List with Jackson in JUnit (Jersey Client)

Tags: json, jaxb, jackson, jersey-client

I recently moved from Jersey 1.X to Jersey 2.1 and using jersey-media-json-jackson for (de-)serializing to Json.

In my JUnit-Test I would like to consume a web service that return a List.
With Jerey 1.x I used to work with GenericType. However, folling code does not work with Jersey 2.1 / Jackson 2.1:

```
GenericType<Collection<String>> listType = new GenericType<Collection<String>>() {};
assertTrue(target("location").request().get(listType).contains("item"));
```

it crashes with

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: 
MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/json, 
type=interface java.util.List, genericType=java.util.Collection<java.lang.String>.
```

Serializing is okay, since following code:

> target("location").request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);

returns a valid Json String

Any ideas how to fix? Any working examples?

---

Versions:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably too late and you found the solution, but here it is for some else who might run into the same problem. Make sure you register the JacksonFeature on a client config before creating your client, code example below.

```
ClientConfig cc = new ClientConfig().register(new JacksonFeature());
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(cc);
WebTarget target = client.target(url);
```